# website over IIS 6 using custom port does not resolve without http prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-6, asp.net-1.1

So I have this asp.net 1.1 website running on IIS 6.0 over an intranet. I am using a different port "86" other than the default port 80 to access the website. The problem I am facing is the website works using the url `http://<IP Address>:86/MyPage.aspx`, however specifying just the IP Address with port number does not resolve to the website page. What configuration am I missing here ? How can i make the url=> `<IPAddress>:86/MyPage.aspx` resolve to my aspx page ?

EDIT : 
What I want is for my users to type in `<IP Address>:86/MyPage.aspx` in the browser window and they should be able to access the page just like by typing in  `http://<IP Address>:86/MyPage.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

There is no default well know mapping for port 86 (unlike 80/443 which maps to http/https), so you must specify protocol portion of Url.

Note that if you are using it as page links you can specify "page relative protocol" like (notice `//` in the beginning):

```
   ...href="//<IPAddress>:86/MyPage.aspx"...
```

Comment: I have edit the description, I want this to work for the users when accessing the page through the browser on their machine. Its not a page that I need to access using some javacsript code or anything like that

Comment: @John I believe you'll need to find how to reconfigure client machines to use additional port-to-protocol mapping (also I don't know where it can be done).

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on browsers for translating your request. There are too many out there considering versions and vendors and can be overwhelming chasing them all down.

Use redirection instead.

1. Add an empty website with a different IP address on port 80 from IIS 6.0.
   If you don’t know how to have multiple IP addresses on one machine look
   at this links:

   [Can My Computer Have More Than One IP Address?](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1925787/computer-address.html)
2. Go to "Properties" and select the “Home Directory” tab.
   Select “A redirection to a URL and from there put your target address (http://:86/MyPage.aspx).

   [Setting up a URL Redirect through IIS](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis/iis-url-redirect/)
3. Tell your users to specify the new IP address with no port. The redirector will do the rest.